# Class does not exist in getRepository doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am new to doctrine and symphony. I have created a small app with curd operation using doctrine ORM. My insertion operation is working but my list operation throws an **error** as

> [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
>       Class 'Tab' does not exist

I will paste my code here:
       **My model file:/var/www/html/silexapp/app/Tnq/Todo/Model/Tab.php**

```
    <?php
   namespace Tnq\Todo\Model;
  // app/Tnq/Todo/Model/Tab.php
  /**
  * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repository_TabRepository")    
  @Table(name="tab")
  */
  class Tab
 {
/** @TAB_ID 
 * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
 * @var int
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @Column(type="string")
 * @var string
 */
protected $description;
/**
 * @Column(type="string")
 * @var string
 */
protected $tabname;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

public function setTabname($tabname)
{
    $this->tabname = $tabname;
}

public function getTabname()
{
    return $this->tabname;
}

}
```

My Doctrine ORM file where i do my curd operation:
**/var/www/html/silexapp/app/Tnq/Todo/Command/Tabcommand.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace Tnq\Todo\Command;

  require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
  //require_once '/var/www/html/silexapp/app/web/bootstrap.php'; 


  use Tnq\Todo\Model as tabmodel;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

  use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition;

class Tabcommand extends Command
{
 protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('todo')
        ->setDescription('Tab Creation')
        ->setDefinition(
            new InputDefinition(array(
                new InputOption('create', 'a'),
                new InputOption('list', 'b'),
                new InputOption('update', 'c'),
                new InputOption('delete', 'd'),
            ))
        )

    ->addOption(
        'tabname',
        null,
        InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
        'Which tab do you want?',
        array('underline', 'bold')
    )
    ->addOption(
        'description',
        null,
        InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
        'tab dexcription'
    )
    ->addOption(
        'id',
        null,
        InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
        'Which id do you want to delete?',
        array('4', '5')
    );

   }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface 
    $output)
    {
    $paths = array('/var/www/html/silexapp/app/Tnq/Todo/Model/');
    $isDevMode = false;

    // the connection configuration
    $dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'mysql',
    'dbname'   => 'foo',
    );

    $config=
    Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths,$isDevMode);
    $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

    $tabmodel = new tabmodel\Tab();

    if ($input->getOption('create')) {
        $this->create($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager);
    }
    if ($input->getOption('update')) {
        $this->update($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager);
    }
    if ($input->getOption('list')) {
        $this->listall($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager);  
    }
    if ($input->getOption('delete')) {
        $this->delete($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager); 
    }

}
protected function create($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager)
{
    $text='';
    $tabname = $tabmodel->setTabname($input->getOption('tabname'));

    $description =    
    $tabmodel->setDescription($input->getOption('description'));
    $entityManager->persist($tabmodel);
    $entityManager->flush();
    $text .= 'Tab creator';
    $text .= 'You are about to ';
    $text .= 'create a Tab.';  
    $text .= 'The Tab Id: '.$tabmodel->getId();
    $text .= 'The Tab Name: '.$tabmodel->getTabname();
    $text .= 'The Tab Description: '.$tabmodel->getDescription();
    $output->writeln($text);
}
protected function update($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager)
{
    $text='';
    $text .= 'Tab Updator : ';
    $text .= 'You are about to ';
    $text .= 'update a Tab.';  
    $text .= 'The id to update: '.$input->getOption('id');
    $text .= 'The tabname to update: '.$input->getOption('tabname');
    $tab = $entityManager->find('Tab', $input->getOption('id'));
    if ($tab === null) {
        $text .= 'The tab id does not exist: '.$input->getOption('id');
    }
    $tab->setName($tabmodel->getTabname());
    $entityManager->flush();
    $output->writeln($text);
}
 public function setRepository(TabRepository $repository)
{
    $this->tabRepository = $repository;

    return $this;
}
protected function listall($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager)
{
    $text='';
    $tabmodel = new tabmodel\Tab();
    $tabRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Tab');
    $tabs = $tabRepository->findAll();
    $text .= 'Tab List : ';
    $text .= 'You are about to ';
    $text .= 'list a Tab.'; 
    foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
        $text .= $tab->getName();
    } 
    $output->writeln($text);
}
protected function delete($input, $output, $tabmodel, $entityManager)
{
    $text='';
    $text .= 'Tab Delete : ';
    $text .= 'You are about to ';
    $text .= 'delete a Tab.';  
    $text .= 'The id to delete: '.$input->getOption('id');
    $output->writeln($text);
}

 }
```

My composer.josn file:

```
    {
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    "symfony/console": "~3.1",
    "doctrine/orm": "v2.5.4"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Cli": "app/",
        "Tnq\\Todo\\Command": "app/",
        "Tnq\\Todo\\Service": "app/",
          "Tnq\\Todo\\Model": "app/"
      }
    }

 }
```

Here My listall getrepository function throws error.
Can anyone help me to find the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass the namespaced class to the getRepository method.  Try:

```
$tabRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Tnq\\Todo\\Model\\Tab');
```

Comment: I tried with the one you have given: I got this error
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tnq\Todo\Model\Repository_TabRepository' not found in /var/www/html/silexapp/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php on line 68

Comment: I will post my composer.json file also

Comment: Yes, It works. I removed my repository and checked. It works. @gview

Comment: Thanks you so much @gview

Comment: For the record: this will break if you ever, for any reason, decide to refactor your code and move this class to a different namespace. Using `Tab::class` will always return the correct fully qualified class name as long as you have the correct `use` statement at the top of your file, which your IDE should do automatically if you use its refactoring tools to move your class.

Comment: Using Tab::class, I tried. but it is not working. It shows only "Class does not exist in getRepository doctrine" error. @YamiTenshi

Comment: @malar You need to put `use Tnq\Todo\Model\Tab'` at the top of your file, after the namespace declaration. That `use` statement should be automatically updated by your IDE if you ever decide to move or rename the class, and as such your code will still work without you having to manually fix the call to `getRepository()`

Comment: In your composer.json, You need to add psr-4 for autoload specific classes.